# Let $A,B$ be two subgroups of $G$. Show that $g(A\cap B)=gA \cap gB$ for all $g \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A,B$ be two subgroups of $G$. Show that $$g(A\cap B)=gA \cap gB$$ for all $g \in G$. I think I have to use inclusion to show it but I have no idea how to start. Can I let $g(a\cap b) \in g(A\cap B)$? But then I don know how to proceed.

Comment: This would be easier to think about if you took $c \in A \cap B$. So this would rephrase your first step to $gc \in g(A \cap B)$. The result basically follows from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $gA \cap gB \subseteq g(A \cap B)$.  Let $x \in gA \cap gB$.  Then $x \in gA$, $x \in gB$  which implies $x = gw_1 = gw_2$, where $w_1 \in A$ and $w_2 \in B$.  Multiply on the left side by $g^{-1}$ and see that $w_1 = w_2 \in B$, so $x \in g(A \cap B)$.

Answer (score 2):

For any fixed $g$, the function $f(x)=gx$ is injective (because inverses exist). It is a general fact about injective functions that $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$ for any subsets $A$, $B$ of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in g(A\cap B)$ then there is an element $w\in (A\cap B)$ such that $x=gw$. $$w\in (A\cap B)\Longrightarrow w\in A,~~~w\in B$$ Then  $x=gw$ and $w\in A$ means that $x\in g A$ and  $x=gw$ and $w\in B$ means that $x\in gB$. So $x\in gA\cap gB$. Follow the inverse path from the last deduction. Try to show that we have a common element in $A$ and $B$ which $x=gw,~~x=gw',~~w\in A, w'\in B$

Comment: Not sure I understand the proof of the reverse inclusion.

Comment: @Did: I wanted to but another answer covered that reverse.

Answer (score 0):

$g (A \cap B)$ are elements of the form $gx$ for some $x \in A$, $x \in B$.

$g A \cap g B$ are elements of the form $gx$ for some $x \in A$, $x \in B$.

therefore they are the same.

Comment: $gA \cap gB$ are elements of the form $gx = gy$ for some $x \in A, y \in B$.

Comment: good point, then hit both sides with $g^{-1}$.

Comment: Maybe. But your second line and the `therefore` are misleading.

Comment: both define the same set so they are the same. the comment spells out how to see the second claim. If you agree with the two claims the result follows... that's why I wrote therefore